# Delphi 2010 How to Set The Initial Folder of the IDE Open Project Dialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Does anyone know how to set the initial folder of the open project or open file dialog in the Delphi 2010 IDE?  For the first time I installed D2010 on a USB hard drive and the open dialog always reverts to the windows drive -D while Delphi is on Drive R.

Comment: I am using Vista so I think the last folder visited overrides the Default Project directory?

Comment: in delphi shortcut change the working folder. [Source](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/149-tools/12950-changing-the-default-project-directory)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Tools|Options|Environment Options, you can set the Default Project directory.

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work since '09?  This answer was probably posted before the service packs - the 'Default Project' doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Comment: @TheSteven: This option is in every version since Delphi 2006.  I just verified with the Enterprise SKUs.  What are you seeing?

Comment: I checked in Delphi Pro 2010 and Xe2 and neither has a 'Default Project' directory. The closest that I see is 'BDSPROJECTDIR' but when I add the override it doesn't work. Maybe it just doesn't like a folder name with a leading underscore e.g. "F:\_My Delphi Projects"

Comment: Odd.  I physically checked every version between D2006 and XE3 before posting and just checked XE4 now.  The option is in every version.  I'm using Enterprise, but it would be odd if it weren't in the Professional SKU.  Can you describe your Environment Options page under Tools|Options?  Especially the section at the bottom named Directories.  What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: System Vars shown: __COMPAT_LAYER, ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, asl.log, BDS, BDSCOMMONDIR, BDSPROJECTSDIR, BDSUSERDIR, CG_BOOST_ROOT, CLASSPATH,  CommonProgramFiles(x86), CommonProgramFiles, CommonProgramW6432, COMPUTERNAME, ComSpec, DELPHI, EL_PATHS, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK, HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH,JAVA_HOME, KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK, LANGDIR, LOCALAPPDATA, LOGONSERVER, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, OS,PATH, PATHEXT, ProgramData, ProgramFiles(x86), ProgramFiles, ProgramW6432, PSModulePath, PTSHOME, PUBLIC, QTJAVA,SESSIONNAME, SystemDrive, SystemRoot, TEMP, TMP, VBOX_INSTALL_PATH, VS100COMNTOOLS, windir

Comment: Had to omit unrelated vars (Adobe..., PROCESSOR..., USER...) couldn't fit everything listed into StackOverflow comment.

Comment: You're describing the Environment Variables page.  The Default Project setting is at the very bottom of the Environment Options page.

Comment: Right there at root level staring me in the face right when I open the Options page. Jeez I'm friggin' blind.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: In Delphi 7; the location is Tools|Environment Options|Preferences tab|Shared Repository Directory, default is empty string which points to 'C:\Program files\Borland\Delphi7\bin'

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify for those who (like me) are looking at their "Environment *variables*" page in the options.. It's not the environment variable BDSPROJECTSDIR! Neither is it any of the other environment variables!

Have a look at the **root** level item in the options screen, "Environment *options*", at the bottom of that page is the "Default project" setting. (easy to miss I guess)

Just checked.. In XE6 and 10.1 the option is still in the same place.

(Thanks to TheSteven and Bruce McGee for providing the answer. Unfortunately, the eureka moment is not very visible in the comments to the last post)