# Delphi not opening projects

Tags: delphi

I have been using Delphi 2010 for some time with no issues but recently every time I try to open a project I get a dialog box asking me to open the project
with a folder that doesn't exist. How do I change the path Delphi opens projects.

Comment: Open what file?

Comment: Delphi isn't opening any projects*.

Comment: Are you talking here about changing Default folder location for Projects? If so then check [Delphi 2010 How to Set The Initial Folder of the IDE Open Project Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369634/3636228) for instructions on how to change it.

Comment: How do you open the projects in Delphi ? Do you do from mainmenu "open recent" or do you browse for a  project, or doubleckick on a dpr file or how ?

Comment: @KadinRaju - Are you talking about new projects or existing projects ?  If it's existing projects then you have a corruption of project files or files/folders have been deleted.  If it's new projects then follow what SilverWarrior has said.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows...(up to 10 anyway)

Right click on the project's DPR and choose Properties.
What does the Opens with: line say? Mine says bdsLauncher.exe
If it says anything else, then you somehow had the system change it directly or indirectly. Virus, installation of some other text editor, whatever...not a big deal in any case. Do the same check for files with extensions DPROJ, GROUPPROJ, ...

If you need to change it, the file should be in a path similar to my C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin except that your version isn't 21.0

I did have issues once upon a time with XE7 where I had to set DPR to open with bds.exe, and DPROJ opened fine with bdsLauncher, but it was probably due to IT's setup of my laptop for someone else, and something with the Win 10 software reset (instead of a format or restore from clone) when they gave it to me. Installing an XE7 update fixed the problem, and it hasn't been an issue since we moved to 10.4